# Routing issue with 404_override

Tags: codeigniter

I'm having an issue with 404_override in CI 2.02.  Here is my default controller and override:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home/index_controller";    
$route['404_override'] = "misc/site_map";
```

This line uncommented gives me this error:

> Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the
>   controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.

But commented, I get a 404 error.  So something in the override is causing the problem.  I just don't know what.  I've tried various MY_Router files and they don't help.  Anyone have any suggestions about how I can fix this?

I've eliminated my .htaccess file as the problem by deleting it from the server and then trying to access a controller that doesn't exist like this: http://domain.com/index.php/doesnotexist.  I still get the error.

Comment: I don't see any error in your code. Please make sure you give controller name properly.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else coming here with this issue, this is/was a bug in CodeIgniter itself to do with 404 pages not being able to be included in subfolders.

[Bug Discussion Including Fix on GitHub](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/939)

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add the default controller that will be used when you first load your website, in your `routes.php` you need to add this, it is required which is why you're seeing the errors being thrown.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'index'; // this will need to be changed to your default controller
$route['404_override'] = 'misc/site_map';
```

EDIT:

Okay, you must make sure you enter the *correct* controller name you wish to load as the default, for example you have `home.php` in your `controllers` folder, you must enter `home` as the default. Optionally, you can define segments that are functions in your `home.php` class file, e.g. `home/function_name`.

Comment: No, I do have that, I just didn't include it in my post.

Comment: My default controller works fine otherwise.  It's only on pages not found that I get this error.  The default controller is my index page and works fine.